# Is the code correct to discover x while using the hash?

Tags: python, hash, generate

I am writing a basic code using python to find what x is with the given hash. However, it is not printing out x when I run it which I believe is because there is not a number in the range 000000-1000000 with the rest of the string to get the hash. I am already given half of the string along with the hash, and x is supposedly only containing **integers** and must be **at least 6 characters** long.

```
import hashlib
for x in range(000000, 1000000):
    line = "user,{x},200981".format(x=x)
    num = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest()
    if (num == "ba520f71e8f8f640423b1f1d4ecea68c81e6ec8c492c2273da348a48e4f407fa"):
        print(x)
        break
```

Is the way I am conducting the x to be a string incorrect or my result for num? I'm new to python so i'm still learning as I go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` you are looking for is apparently not in the range `000000 - 1000000`.

It is `18273349`.

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> for x in count():
...   line = "user,{x},200981".format(x=x)
...   num = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest()
...   if (num == "ba520f71e8f8f640423b1f1d4ecea68c81e6ec8c492c2273da348a48e4f407fa"):
...      print(x)
...      break
... 
18273349
```

Here, instead of a fixed range, I used [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to count to infinity until `x` is found.

```
>>> line = "user,{x},200981".format(x=18273349)
>>> num = hashlib.sha256(line.encode()).hexdigest()
>>> num
'ba520f71e8f8f640423b1f1d4ecea68c81e6ec8c492c2273da348a48e4f407fa'
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that while you're writing your numbers with 6 digits that doesn't really matter to python: 0, 00, 000, 0000, 00000 and 000000 are all the same: 0. And when you format your string, that's exactly what Python will insert:

```py
>>> 000000
0
>>> format(000000, '')
'0'
```

As a result, your formatted string will be something along the lines of `bucky,743,20200128` or `bucky,6913,20200128`, which as you can see *does not have 6 digits for the middle / formatted number*. So the number to find is anywhere between 0 and 99999 you won't ever find it.

In which case you may want to [*zero-pad*](https://pyformat.info/#number_padding) the number to 6 digits when formatting it:

```py
line = "bucky,{x:06},20200128".format(x=x)
```

However it's also probable that

### you're misreading / misunderstanding the problem itself:

> and x is supposedly only containing integers and must be at least 6 characters long.

I don't know whether that's the problem as posed or your rephrasing of it of it, but an interpretation of that would be that `x` is *a number of at least 6 digits* (which generally excludes any leading zero) aka you're not looking for a number of 1-6 digits padded to 6, you're looking for a number higher than *10<sup>6</sup>*